# Lua Love2D Error: Syntax error: main.lua:1: '=' expected

Tags: lua, love2d

I was trying to create a love2d 2 person game when I ran into this error. I have no clue on how to fix it and I am new to love2d. I tried to look through my code many times, but could not seem to find the answer. I thought that it was a problem with my equal signs, so I look through it and they were fine. So, can anyone explain how I got this error? Thanks in advance!

```
   function love.load()

-- Border Data
    b = {}
    b.y = 0
    b.x = 0

-- Player Data
    p1 = {}
    p2 = {}
    -- Player Positions 
    p1.x = 105
    p1.y = 920
    p2.x = 355
    p2.y = 920
    -- Player Points
    p1.points = 0
    p2.points = 0

    -- Extra Data
    Level = 1
    candrawenemys = true
    p1.won = false
    p2.won = false
    candrawin = false

    function playerWon(player)
        if player == p1 then
            candrawenemys = false
            p1.won = true
            candrawin = true
        elseif player == p2 then
            candrawenemys = false
            candrawin = true
            p2.won = true
        end
    end

-- Enemy Data
    e1 = {}
    e2 = {}
    e3 = {}
    e4 = {}
    e5 = {}
    enemy = {}
    enemy.speed = 2

-- Enemy 1 Data
    e1.y = 170
    e1.x = 0
    e1.speed = enemy.speed
    e1.direction = "front"

-- Enemy 2 Data
    e2.y = 340
    e2.x = 480
    e2.speed = enemy.speed
    e2.direction = "back"

-- Enemy 3 Data
    e3.y = 510
    e3.x = 0
    e3.speed = enemy.speed
    e3.direction = "front"

-- Enemy 4 Data
    e4.y = 680
    e4.x = 480
    e4.speed = enemy.speed
    e4.direction = "back"

-- Enemy 5 Data
    e5.y = 850
    e5.x = 0
    e5.speed = enemy.speed
    e5.direction = "front"

end




function love.update(dt)

-- KEYBOARD Functions
    if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
        p1.y = p1.y - 3
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("s") then
        p1.y = p1.y + 3
    end 
    if love.keyboard.isDown("a") then
        p1.x = p1.x - 3
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
        p1.x = p1.x + 3
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("up") then
        p2.y = p2.y - 3 
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("down") then
        p2.y = p2.y + 3
    end 
    if love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
        p2.x = p2.x - 3 
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
        p2.x = p2.x + 3
    end

    if candrawin == true then
        if love.keyboard.isDown("r") then
            print("button pressed")
            candrawenemys = true
            p1.won = false
            p2.won = false
            enemy.speed = 2
            e1.y = 170
            e1.x = 0
            e2.y = 340
            e2.x = 480
            e3.y = 510
            e3.x = 0
            e4.y = 680
            e4.x = 480
            e5.y = 850
            e5.x = 0
            p1.x = 105
            p1.y = 920
            p2.x = 355
            p2.y = 920
            candrawin = false
        end
    end

-- Winning
    if p1.points == 1 then
        playerWon(p1)
    elseif p2.points == 1 then
        playerWon(p2)
    end




-- Finish Line Collision
    if p1.x < b.x+500 and b.x < p1.x+20 and p1.y < b.y+50 and b.y < p1.y+30 then
        p1.points = p1.points + 1
        Level = Level + 1
        p1.x = 105
        p1.y = 920
        p2.x = 355
        p2.y = 920
        enemy.speed = enemy.speed + 2
        end
    if p2.x < b.x+500 and b.x < p2.x+20 and p2.y < b.y+50 and b.y < p2.y+30 then
        p2.points = p2.points + 1
        Level = Level + 1
        p1.x = 105
        p1.y = 920
        p2.x = 355
        p2.y = 920
        enemy.speed = enemy.speed + 2
        end

-- Enemies Moving

-- Enemy 1
    if e1.direction == "front" then
        e1.x = e1.x + enemy.speed
    end
    if e1.direction == "back" then

        e1.x = e1.x - enemy.speed
    end

    if e1.x >= 480 then
        e1.direction = "back"
    elseif e1.x <= 0 then
        e1.direction = "front"
    end




-- Enemy 2
    if e2.direction == "front" then
        e2.x = e2.x + enemy.speed
    end
    if e2.direction == "back" then
        e2.x = e2.x - enemy.speed
    end

    if e2.x >= 480 then
        e2.direction = "back"
    elseif e2.x <= 0 then
        e2.direction = "front"
    end




-- Enemy 3
    if e3.direction == "front" then
        e3.x = e3.x + enemy.speed
    end
    if e3.direction == "back" then

        e3.x = e3.x - enemy.speed
    end

    if e3.x >= 480 then
        e3.direction = "back"
    elseif e3.x <= 0 then
        e3.direction = "front"
    end




-- Enemy 4
    if e4.direction == "front" then
        e4.x = e4.x + enemy.speed
    end
    if e4.direction == "back" then

        e4.x = e4.x - enemy.speed
    end

    if e4.x >= 480 then
        e4.direction = "back"
    elseif e4.x <= 0 then
        e4.direction = "front"
    end




-- Enemy 5
    if e5.direction == "front" then
        e5.x = e5.x + enemy.speed
    end
    if e5.direction == "back" then

        e5.x = e5.x - enemy.speed
    end

    if e5.x >= 480 then
        e5.direction = "back"
    elseif e5.x <= 0 then
        e5.direction = "front"
    end

end




function love.draw()
-- Basic Setup

-- Drawing if Won
    if candrawin == true then
        if p1.won == true then
            p1.x = 250
            p1.y = 275
            love.graphics.print("Player 1 Won!", 200, 200, 0, 2,2)
            love.graphics.print("Press 'r' to play again!", 125, 700, 0, 2, 2)
        end
    end
    if candrawin == true then
        if p2.won == true then
            p2.x = 250
            p2.y = 275
            love.graphics.print("Player 2 Won!", 200, 200, 0, 2,2)
            love.graphics.print("Press 'r' to play again!", 125, 700, 0, 2, 2)
        end 
    end

-- Draw Score
    if candrawenemys == true then
        love.graphics.print("Player 1 Points: ".. p1.points, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2)
        love.graphics.print("Player 2 Points: ".. p2.points, 280, 0, 0, 2, 2)
    end

-- Draw Finish Line
    if candrawenemys == true then
        love.graphics.rectangle("line", b.x, b.y, 500, 50)
    end

-- Draw Players
    love.graphics.setColor(0,0,255)
    if p2.won == false then
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", p1.x, p1.y, 30,30)
    end
    love.graphics.setColor(255,0,0)
    if p1.won == false then
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", p2.x, p2.y, 30,30)
    end

-- Draw all enemies
    if candrawenemys == true then
        love.graphics.setColor(0,255,0)
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", e1.x, e1.y, 20,20)
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", e2.x, e2.y, 20,20)
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", e3.x, e3.y, 20,20)
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", e4.x, e4.y, 20,20)
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", e5.x, e5.y, 20,20)
    end

end
```

Comment: The code you've shared doesn't have a syntax error. Double check that what you've posted is the file causing your problem

Comment: I just reset the code and copied it directly.

Comment: I can confirm that the file looks perfectly valid, and `luac -p -l` has no problem compiling it. Make sure you're really loading the right file. You may be starting love in the wrong directory, or with a `.love` file by accident.